# Mongoose Subdocuments in Nest.js

Tags: reference, schema, nestjs, subdocument

I'm moving my app from express.js to Nest.js, and I can't find a way to reference one mongoose Schema in another, without using old way of declaring Schema with mongoose.Schema({...}).

Let's use example from docs, so I can clarify my problem:

```js
@Schema()
  export class Cat extends Document {
  @Prop()
  name: string;
}

export const CatSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Cat);
```

Now, what I want is something like this:

```js
@Schema()
export class Owner extends Document {
  @Prop({type: [Cat], required: true})
  cats: Cat[];
}

export const OwnerSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Owner);
```

When I define schemas this way I'd get an error, something like this: **Invalid schema configuration: `Cat` is not a valid
type within the array `cats`**

So, what is the proper way for referencing one Schema inside another, using this more OO approach for defining Schemas?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

I dug into the source code and learned how Schema class is converted by the `SchemaFactory.createForClass` method.

## Well so how it works?

### 1. Take a look at this example below:

```js
@Schema()
export class Cat extends Document {
  @Prop()
  name: string;
}
export const catSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Cat);
```

Basically, when you do `SchemaFactory.createForClass(Cat)`

Nest will convert the class syntax into the Mongoose schema syntax, so in the end, the result of the conversion would be like this:

```js
const schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: { type: String } // Notice that `String` is now uppercase.
});
```

### 2. How does the conversion work?

Take a look at this file: [mongoose/prop.decorator.ts at master · nestjs/mongoose · GitHub](https://github.com/nestjs/mongoose/blob/master/lib/decorators/prop.decorator.ts)

```js
export function Prop(options?: PropOptions): PropertyDecorator {
  return (target: object, propertyKey: string | symbol) => {
    options = (options || {}) as mongoose.SchemaTypeOpts<unknown>;

    const isRawDefinition = options[RAW_OBJECT_DEFINITION];
    if (!options.type && !Array.isArray(options) && !isRawDefinition) {
      const type = Reflect.getMetadata(TYPE_METADATA_KEY, target, propertyKey);

      if (type === Array) {
        options.type = [];
      } else if (type && type !== Object) {
        options.type = type;
      }
    }

    TypeMetadataStorage.addPropertyMetadata({
      target: target.constructor,
      propertyKey: propertyKey as string,
      options,
    });
  };
}
```

Here you could see what the `Prop()` decorator does behind the scene.
When you do:

```js
@Prop()
name: string;
```

`Prop` function would be called, in this case with no arguments.

```js
const type = Reflect.getMetadata(TYPE_METADATA_KEY, target, propertyKey);
```

Using the `Reflect` API, we can get the data type that you use when you do `name: string`. The value of `type` variable is now set to `String`. Notice that it’s not `string`, the `Reflect` API will always return the constructor version of the data type so:

- `number` will be serialized as `Number`
- `string` will be serialized as `String`
- `boolean` will be serialized as `Boolean`
- and so on

`TypeMetadataStorage.addPropertyMetadata` will then store the object below into the store.

```js
{
    target: User,
    propertyKey: ‘name’,
    options: { type: String }
}
```

Let’s take a look at the: [mongoose/type-metadata.storage.ts at master · nestjs/mongoose · GitHub](https://github.com/nestjs/mongoose/blob/master/lib/storages/type-metadata.storage.ts)

```js
export class TypeMetadataStorageHost {
  private schemas = new Array<SchemaMetadata>();
  private properties = new Array<PropertyMetadata>();

  addPropertyMetadata(metadata: PropertyMetadata) {
    this.properties.push(metadata);
  }
}
```

So basically that object will be stored into the `properties` variable in `TypeMetadataStorageHost`.
`TypeMetadataStorageHost` is a singleton that will store a lot of these objects.

### 3. Schema generation

To understand how the `SchemaFactory.createForClass(Cat)` produce the Mongoose schema, take a look at this: [mongoose/schema.factory.ts at master · nestjs/mongoose · GitHub](https://github.com/nestjs/mongoose/blob/master/lib/factories/schema.factory.ts)

```js
export class SchemaFactory {
  static createForClass(target: Type<unknown>) {
    const schemaDefinition = DefinitionsFactory.createForClass(target);
    const schemaMetadata = TypeMetadataStorage.getSchemaMetadataByTarget(
      target,
    );
    return new mongoose.Schema(
      schemaDefinition,
      schemaMetadata && schemaMetadata.options,
    );
  }
}
```

The most important part is:
`const schemaDefinition = DefinitionsFactory.createForClass(target);`. Notice that the target here is your `Cat` class.

You could see the method definition here: [mongoose/definitions.factory.ts at master · nestjs/mongoose · GitHub](https://github.com/nestjs/mongoose/blob/master/lib/factories/definitions.factory.ts)

```js
export class DefinitionsFactory {
  static createForClass(target: Type<unknown>): mongoose.SchemaDefinition {
    let schemaDefinition: mongoose.SchemaDefinition = {};

  schemaMetadata.properties?.forEach((item) => {
    const options = this.inspectTypeDefinition(item.options as any);
    schemaDefinition = {
    [item.propertyKey]: options as any,
      …schemaDefinition,
    };
  });

    return schemaDefinition;
}
```

`schemaMetadata.properties` contains the object that you stored when you did `TypeMetadataStorage.addPropertyMetadata`:

```js
[
    {
        target: User,
        propertyKey: ‘name’,
        options: { type: String }
    }
]
```

The `forEach` will produce:

```js
{
    name: { type: String }
}
```

In the end, it will be used as the argument to the `mongoose.Schema` constructor [mongoose/schema.factory.ts at master · nestjs/mongoose · GitHub](https://github.com/nestjs/mongoose/blob/master/lib/factories/schema.factory.ts):

```js
return new mongoose.Schema(
    schemaDefinition,
    schemaMetadata && schemaMetadata.options,
);
```

### 4. So to answer the question:

What should you put as the  `Prop()` argument?

Remember when Nest does the `forEach` to generate the Mongoose Schema?

```js
schemaMetadata.properties?.forEach((item) => {
  const options = this.inspectTypeDefinition(item.options as any);
  schemaDefinition = {
    [item.propertyKey]: options as any,
    …schemaDefinition,
  };
});
```

To get the `options` it uses `inspectTypeDefinition` method. You could see the definition below:

```js
private static inspectTypeDefinition(options: mongoose.SchemaTypeOpts<unknown> | Function): PropOptions {
  if (typeof options === 'function') {
    if (this.isPrimitive(options)) {
      return options;
    } else if (this.isMongooseSchemaType(options)) {
      return options;
    }
    return this.createForClass(options as Type<unknown>);   
  } else if (typeof options.type === 'function') {
    options.type = this.inspectTypeDefinition(options.type);
    return options;
  } else if (Array.isArray(options)) {
    return options.length > 0
      ? [this.inspectTypeDefinition(options[0])]
      : options;
  }
  return options;
}
```

### Here you could draw the conclusion that:

1. If the `options` is a `function` such as `String` or a `SchemaType` it will be returned directly and used as the Mongoose options.
2. If the `options` is an `Array`, it will return the first index of that array and wrap it in an array.
3. If the `options` is not an `Array` or `function`, for example, if it’s only a plain `object` such as `{ type: String, required: true }`, it will be returned directly and used as the Mongoose options.

### Answer

So to add a reference from `Cat` to `Owner`, you could do:

```js
import { Prop, Schema, SchemaFactory } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { Document, Schema as MongooseSchema } from 'mongoose';
import { Owner } from './owner.schema.ts';

@Schema()
export class Cat extends Document {
  @Prop()
  name: string;

  @Prop({ type: MongooseSchema.Types.ObjectId, ref: Owner.name })
  owner: Owner;
}

export const catSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Cat);
```

As for how to add a reference from `Owner` to `Cat`, we could do:

```js
@Prop([{ type: MongooseSchema.Types.ObjectId, ref: Cat.name }])
```

### Update

To answer the question in the comment section about:

#### How to embed schema in another schema?

If you read the answer properly, you should have enough knowledge to do this. But if you didn't, here's the TLDR answer.

Note that I strongly recommend you to read the entire answer before you go here.

**image-variant.schema.ts**

```js
import { Prop, Schema, SchemaFactory } from '@nestjs/mongoose';

@Schema()
export class ImageVariant {
  @Prop()
  url: string;

  @Prop()
  width: number;

  @Prop()
  height: number;

  @Prop()
  size: number;
}

export const imageVariantSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(ImageVariant);
```

**image.schema.ts**

```js
import { Prop, Schema, SchemaFactory } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { Document } from 'mongoose';
import { imageVariantSchema, ImageVariant } from './imagevariant.schema';

@Schema()
export class Image extends Document {
  @Prop({ type: imageVariantSchema })
  large: ImageVariant;

  @Prop({ type: imageVariantSchema })
  medium: ImageVariant;

  @Prop({ type: imageVariantSchema })
  small: ImageVariant;
}

export const imageSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Image);
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Great explanation, thanks a lot!

Comment: This does not answer the question though. How to create nested schema with decorators?

Comment: @Sinandro instead of 

@Prop({type: [Cat]}) you write 

@Prop([{ type: MongooseSchema.Types.ObjectId, ref: Cat.name }]) .

Could you provide an example on what you mean?

Comment: Well, this is not a nested schema, it's only a foreign key to the Cat schema. The question was how to create a nested schema. The cat should be saved inside the Owner, not on a separate collection.

Comment: @Sinandro The question was "referencing one Schema inside another" not "embedding schema inside another". Your question is a different question. Please take a look at
`else if (typeof options.type === 'function')` in the `inspectTypeDefinition` method. That's the answer that you want.

Comment: @EdwardAnthony in your example, how would you save a Cat inside an Owner.cats array ? I use Owner.cats.push(catDocument) and it saves an entire document instead of just the id. If I push only the id - I get a type error because the Owner Schema is defined as "cats: Cat[]"

Comment: @Yaron It won't save the entire document. As long as you specify the `ref` in the `@Prop` decorator, it will be saved as a relation reference, therefore it will only save the id. This functionality doesn't come from `@nestjs/mongoose` library, it comes from Mongoose.

Comment: What about the mongoose helper functions such as `parent.subdoc.id(someID)` since the types are defined on class props and typescript will complain they don't exist on the type. Simply adding an intersection like `@Prop({ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: Cats.name }) cats: Cats[] & Document;` allows mongoose helper functions but now TS complains anytime we try to use direct assignment for subdocs like `owner.cats = [...listOfCats ]`. The latter is sometimes useful for editing a document instance in place. How can we satisfy both former and the latter to make full use of mongoose in Nestjs?

Comment: Its a bit cumbersome but I've resolved it. Setup requires casting the subdocs where using the instance as in `const lineItems = order.lineItems as Document & OrderLineItem[]; const item = lineItems.id(itemId);` Extra work because you have to create an extra variable to type the subdocs but this allows the use of the query helpers as well as keeping the Class ref on the prop types of the parent class.

Answer (score 3):

Create `SchemaFactory.createForClass` for the SubDocument and refer to its type in the Document.

```js
    import { Prop, Schema, SchemaFactory } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
    
    @Schema()
    export class SubDocument {
     @Prop()
      name: string;
    
      @Prop()
      description: number;
    }
    
    const subDocumentSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(SubDocument);
    
    @Schema()
    export class Document {
      @Prop()
      name: string;
    
      @Prop({ type: subDocumentSchema })
      subDocument: SubDocument;
    }
    
    export const documentSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Document);
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
import { Prop, raw, Schema, SchemaFactory } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';
import { Education } from '../../education/schemas';
import { RECORD_STATUS } from '../../common/common.constants';
import { Employment } from '../../employment/schemas';
import {
    JOB_SEARCH_STATUS,
    LANGUAGE_PROFICIENCY
} from '../user-profile.constants';

const externalLinks = {
    linkedInUrl: { type: String },
    githubUrl: { type: String },
    twitterUrl: { type: String },
    blogUrl: { type: String },
    websiteUrl: { type: String },
    stackoverflowUrl: { type: String }
};

const address = {
    line1: { type: String, required: true },
    line2: { type: String },
    zipCode: { type: String },
    cityId: { type: Number },
    countryId: { type: Number }
};

const language = {
    name: { type: String, require: true },
    code: { type: String, required: true },
    proficiency: { type: String, required: true, enum: LANGUAGE_PROFICIENCY }
};

const options = {
    timestamps: true,
};

export type UserProfileDocument = UserProfile & mongoose.Document;

@Schema(options)
export class UserProfile {

    _id: string;

    @Prop()
    firstName: string;

    @Prop()
    lastName: string;

    @Prop()
    headline: string;

    @Prop({
        unique: true,
        trim: true,
        lowercase: true
    })
    email: string;

    @Prop()
    phoneNumber: string

    @Prop(raw({
        jobSearchStatus: { type: String, enum: JOB_SEARCH_STATUS, required: true }
    }))
    jobPreferences: Record<string, any>;

    @Prop(raw(externalLinks))
    externalLinks: Record<string, any>;

    @Prop([String])
    skills: string[];

    @Prop(raw({ type: address, required: false }))
    address: Record<string, any>;

    @Prop()
    birthDate: Date;

    @Prop({ type: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Employment' }] })
    employments: Employment[];

    @Prop({ type: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Education' }] })
    educations: Education[];

    @Prop(raw([language]))
    languages: Record<string, any>[];

    @Prop()
    timeZone: string;

    @Prop()
    createdAt: Date;

    @Prop()
    updatedAt: Date;

    @Prop({
        enum: RECORD_STATUS,
        required: true,
        default: RECORD_STATUS.Active
    })
    recordStatus: string;
}

export const UserProfileSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(UserProfile);
```